# What does System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.IdentityType.Name specify?

Tags: c#, active-directory

If we refer to the documentation for `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.IdentityType`, it identifies `IdentityType.Name` as '[The identity is a name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356425.aspx)' and nothing more.  What name does this mean? What format does it expect?

This doesn't work:

```
UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(myContext, IdentityType.Name, "John Doe");
```

Neither does this:

```
UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(myContext, IdentityType.Name, "Doe, John");
```

Nor this:

```
UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(myContext, IdentityType.Name, "jdoe"); //The username
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "doesn't work", but I presume you mean it returns null and doesn't throw an exception.

The short answer of how it works: `IdentityType.Name` maps to the `Name` property of the underlying `Principal` object: [Principal.Name Property on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.name.aspx). If you look at the other properties of `Principal`, you'll notice they map to the other enums of `IdentityType`.

Depending on how your directory was set up, a user's `Name` property may not be what you expect. For example, "jdoe" might actually be the user's `SamAccountName` property but not the `Name`. That's probably what's going on here, or you're targeting the wrong context (unintended domain or local machine). I would double check the user's properties either programmatically or by firing up dsa.msc.

Unless you want to specifically target the `Name` property, consider using [the other `FindByIdentity` method that searches all of the `IdentityType` enumerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383475.aspx). Then if you use the code below and "jdoe" is actually the `SamAccountName`, you'll still find the user you're looking for:

```
var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "jdoe");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my question wasn't marvellous.. This approach works fine for the other identitytypes (we need a unique ref like SID or UPN), the question was just to clarify what this enumerator referred to - thanks!